# Debugging Report DP class

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have noticed that I can debug the DP class of the AX standard reports using the AX debugger running on my client machine. This is not something I can do with my own custom written reports. Also, I thought this code ran in CLR on the reporting server so should not be able to be debugged. So my question is what is the explanation for this, and is there any way I can utilize this capability for my custom written reports.

Comment: Have you checked option  "Execute Business operations in CIL"? This could be the reason why the code of the data provider does not run in CIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether your custom written classes extend `SRSReportDataProviderBase`, and those classes that you can debug extend `SrsReportDataProviderPreProcess`.